# STM32 - UART overrun error when reception occurs

Tags: embedded, stm32, uart

I am developing a simple application on STM32F051. I have two boards that are supposed to communicate with each other. Data is sent from one to the other, then two bytes are sent back indicating whether the transfer was a success. I have a problem with data reception via UART, I only get the first byte, then the MCU indicates an Overrun condition.

Honestly, I have no idea what might be wrong. The MCU is running at 48MHz, that's plenty fast to handle only 2 bytes of incoming information @ 56k baud one would think. There are no interrupts that might interfere with the routine. Everything is so simple, I've never run into such problem before. What might be happening here?

2nd question, is it worth to calculate and send CRC of only one byte of data?

```
//Iterate until the transfer was completed succesfully
while(!transfer_success)
{
    while(SD_menu_select());

    //2 data bytes are to be expected
    //Store data in temporary register
    while(!(USART2->ISR & USART_FLAG_RXNE));
    temp_data[0] = (uint8_t)(USART2->RDR & (uint16_t)0x01FF);

    //char urt_buf_t[30];
    /*lcd_write_cmd(1);
    sprintf(urt_buf_t, "UART:%X", temp_data[0]);
    lcd_str_XY(0,0, urt_buf_t);*/

    while(!(USART2->ISR & USART_FLAG_RXNE));
    temp_data[1] = (uint8_t)(USART2->RDR & (uint16_t)0x01FF);

    lcd_write_cmd(1);
    lcd_str_XY(0,0, "STEP:uart data2");

    //Parse the received data
    //First byte indicates whether the data transfer was succesful
    //Second one is just a CRC8 value
    if((temp_data[0] == 0xAA) && (temp_data[1] == 0x27))
    {
        //1st byte is equal to AA
        //Success
        transfer_success = 1;
        break;
    }

    if((temp_data[0] == 0x27) && (temp_data[1] == 0x11))
    {
        /*lcd_write_cmd(1);
        lcd_str_XY(0,0, "Blad transferu.");
        lcd_str_XY(0,1, "Wybierz plik aby");
        lcd_str_XY(0,2, "sprobowac ponownie.");*/
    }
    lcd_write_cmd(1);
    lcd_str_XY(0,0, "STEP:parse");
}
```

Comment: What type is "temp_data" and where is it allocated? How large rx buffer do you have in the UART? If it's just one byte large you can't be writing to a display in the middle of reception. Also, unrelated to your problem you have lots of incorrect casts in this code that indicate that you need to study how implicit type promotions work in C.

Comment: uint8_t temp_data[3] = {0}; is defined in main
Maybe You noticed that the lines you mentioned are commented. They are there just for debug purposes

Comment: Probably you're not fast enough. You got some hundred microseconds to free RDR. Sprintf usually is a pretty big function, you get probably lost there. Also check the execution time for lcd_str_XY, or just try comment them, and check if you still get an overrun.